Making multiple elements draggable to any location the user wants on the screen and having them stay there
I've got 9 DIV elements on a page all with the class cell, and this is the code I have so far... it was working to drag them anywhere on the screen, but I screwed it up somehow because it's not working now it might be because I've tried multiple codes to do the same thing with no results, but here is the relevant code that I've tried.


document.getElementById("cell*").onmousedown = function(e) {
  this.prevX = e.clientX;
  this.prevY = e.clientY;
  this.mouseDown = true;
}
document.getElementById("cell*").onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (this.mouseDown) {
    this.style.left = (Number(this.style.left.substring(0, this.style.left.length - 2)) + (e.clientX - this.prevX)) + "px";
    this.style.top = (Number(this.style.top.substring(0, this.style.top.length - 2)) + (e.clientY - this.prevY)) + "px";
  }
  this.prevX = e.clientX;
  this.prevY = e.clientY;
}
document.getElementById("cell*").onmouseup = function() {
  this.mouseDown = false;
}

let cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
for (list of cells) {
  list.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    let selected = draggable;
  })
}
class PyramidCell {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.isDragging = false;
    this.currentX = 0;
    this.currentY = 0;
    this.initialX = 0;
    this.initialY = 0;
    this.xOffset = 0;
    this.yOffset = 0;

    // Call setup functions
    this.setupEventListeners();
  }

  setupEventListeners() {
    this.element.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.dragStart(e));
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => this.drag(e));
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => this.dragEnd());
  }

  dragStart(e) {
    this.initialX = e.clientX - this.xOffset;
    this.initialY = e.clientY - this.yOffset;

    if (draggable === this.element) {
      this.isDragging = true;
      this.element.classList.add('dragging');
    }
  }

  drag(e) {
    if (this.isDragging) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.currentX = e.clientX - this.initialX;
      this.currentY = e.clientY - this.initialY;
      this.xOffset = this.currentX;
      this.yOffset = this.currentY;

      this.setTranslate(this.currentX, this.currentY);
    }
  }

  dragEnd() {
    this.initialX = this.currentX;
    this.initialY = this.currentY;
    this.isDragging = false;
    this.element.classList.remove('dragging');
  }

  setTranslate(xPos, yPos) {
    this.element.style.transform = `translate(${xPos}px, ${yPos}px)`;
  }
}

// Initialize all cells
document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach((cell) => {
  new PyramidCell(cell);
})
cell {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--cell-size);
  height: var(--cell-size);
  border-radius: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: move;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 1;
  set-draggable: true;
}

.cell.dragging {
  border-radius: 24%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
<div id="cell7" class="cell" data-content="mgmt">
</div>



It worked once, but then I changed the colors/opacity of the cells and they suddenly weren't draggable anymore and I had to put something here to post the question.

I am not sure what is going on with your JS, but I know there is a much easier way to do it.
A few things to note: ensure that your CSS variable "cell-size" is set and that you can actually see the box. Also, remove the "transition:" CSS attribute because that screws up the dragging effect.
Here is some code:


document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach((cell) => {
    dragInit(cell);
});

function dragInit(elem) {
  var newX = 0, newY = 0, initalX = 0, initialY = 0;
  elem.onmousedown = mouseDownDrag;

  function mouseDownDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    initialX = e.clientX;
    initialY = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = () => {document.onmouseup = null; document.onmousemove = null;};
    document.onmousemove = dragDiv;
  }

  function dragDiv(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    
    newX = initialX - e.clientX;
    newY = initialY - e.clientY;
    initialX = e.clientX;
    initialY = e.clientY;
    elem.style.left = (elem.offsetLeft - newX) + "px";
    elem.style.top = (elem.offsetTop - newY) + "px";
  }
}
.cell {
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--cell-size);
    height: var(--cell-size);
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    cursor: move;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.8);
    background-color:red;
    z-index: 1;
}
:root{
  --cell-size: 100px
}
<div id="cell7" class="cell" data-content="mgmt"></div>



